# How to disable all animations?

Tags: openbox, lxde, animation

I'm using LXDE with Openbox.I hate that animations slow down work.

How to disable all animations completely?

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the file `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

Change:

```
<animateIconify>yes</animateIconify>
```

to

```
<animateIconify>no</animateIconify>
```

P.S.: If you are under lubuntu the file can also be named `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

Comment: Use `openbox --reconfigure` to reload the config.